# How can I use bpy as a module in an IDE?

Tags: python

I am new to blender and python and need to get something done.  I want to use an IDE to help me along.  The inability of VS or PYCharm to be able to recognize bpy.types really is slowing me down.

Yes, there is a solution that include compiling (??) a Py Module (??) but I really don't understand it and it seems like its very advanced for a beginner.

Does anybody have the files I need?  Can anybody just make them?

---

Thanks for the answer.  I knew when I wrote this that the Module was not part of the official build.

LEt's see if I can state my case differently.  I've written code for decades yet I'm new to blender and python.  I've watched the videos and reviewed all the example code.  I'm ready to start by making small incremental changes to the examples.  First up is getting my dev environment working.  An IDE with code checking and code complete will cut my learning time by 90%.  Blender, Visual Studio or PyCharm. Go.  Then I run into a wall.

Code checking and code complete don't work.

After a day of research, I find that there's a workaround.  Compile as a module (??).  But this seems to be the most advanced process.  The instructions assume (and say) that you must have experience.  I don't.

It seems like at least a day, and the likelihood of success is low.

I don't believe my situation is unique.  If the goal is to encourage more use and development, solving this is in everybody's interest.

Is there somebody out there that can do this in a half hour?  Somebody experienced who knows exactly what to do?  Somebody with the dev environment ready to take this on and only needs to work a few minutes to accomplish this?

Could someone do this for the current build and post it?  Newbies like me will appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome doby :) You want to use bpy as module for python, right?

Comment: Yes.  At least i believe that's what I want.  See new comment.

Answer (score 4):

The blender as a module build is not officially supported which means the blender foundation won't make it available as part of the normal blender releases, which means [compiling blender yourself](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3AIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) is currently the only way to get a copy of blender as a module.

[Graphicall.org](http://www.graphicall.org) is a site that makes custom builds of development and experimental versions of blender available. It could be worth commenting on one of the builds for your system to see if the builder might be persuaded to make a module build available.

Comment: I downloaded builds from Graphicall and none had a bpy in them.

I also downloaded cmake, git and the python and attempted to fulfill the instructions, and could get nothing to happen.  About three hours of work and looking very unllikely.

Comment: So far no none has offered a bpy module build, but if you leave a comment to the builders saying you would like a copy of blender as a module they may start offering it. There does appear to be a growing interest in using it so if the graphicall builders start to get a few requests for it some may start providing it.

Comment: I have tried many many times to get a BPY module build to work. I have a normal compile working fine.. let me try again and see if I can get it to work ;)