# Where is Bleders bpy Python library located

Tags: python, add-on, external-applications

I've been a text editor (Visual Studio Code) and somebody made an awesome add-on that lets you deploy python, and for that its great! but to be able of read an external api you need to tell some file where is located, so I would like to know where the bpy and preferably the bge files are, and of course all it dependencies.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42520/blender-module-bpy