# Python: Using pycharm with the blender API gives errors

Tags: python, scripting, workflow

I was trying to follow this [tutorial](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/using-external-ide-pycharm-for-writing-blender-scripts/) to use Pycharm with blender. I extracted the API from blender but when trying to use the bpy library, I get multiple errors. Is there some way to fix this or download a more stable version?

I get an error like this:

> def template_list(listtype_name, list_id="", dataptr, propname, active_dataptr, active_propname, item_dyntip_propname="", rows=5, maxrows=5, type='DEFAULT', columns=9):' ^ SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

This is after I fixed 7 errors. I know how to fix it but its a huge hassle to fix all the errors.

File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbi4r417p8qeq7y/bpy.py?dl=0

Comment: I get an error like this: 
'def template_list(listtype_name, list_id="", dataptr, propname, active_dataptr, active_propname, item_dyntip_propname="", rows=5, maxrows=5, type='DEFAULT', columns=9):'
                     ^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

This is after I fixed 7 errors. I know how to fix it but its a huge hassle to fix all the errors.

Comment: Where does the `template_list` method come from? `list_id=""` is known as a default argument, ie it has a default value of "".  It needs to be in argument list  after the non-default arguments.

Comment: It is in the bpy file I posted above, line 76158

Comment: What version of blender? did you read the **important note** at then end of step 4?

Comment: I did read the important note. I have blender 2.79 which they said: "does not work correctly with Blender newer than 2.78."

Comment: Hmm, been thinking of giving pycharm a run myself.  Did you try the API defs in link associated with important note?

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42539/935) suggests building blender as a module which can be imported in IDEs outside of blender. [This one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49846/935) links to a code.blender article that has an addon to use pycharm to debug a script that is running in blender.

Comment: I’ve been thinking of building blender. If I did it on Linux would it work with windows?